# How do I vent a floor drain and toilet sharing a common drain on the second floor?

Tags: plumbing

Can the upper portion of a sanitary tee installed vertically in the  stack be used as a *vent* if both a floor drain and toilet enter it at the same level through a common drain (**wye**) and there are no fixtures above?  Plumber in Albany N.Y. looking for clarification...

Comment: please remove all-caps

Comment: A diagram or picture might help clarify the question.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because, on second thought, a diagram or additional information is really required. There are simply too many factors and the question is too ambiguous. Is the system wet vented? Is it an emergency floor drain? By common drain, do you mean the waste stack?  Where in the stack would the sanitary tee be installed (vent side)? Is the intention to dry-vent an emergency floor drain in an already wet-vented system?